# How to turn on /off the capabilities through a Windows 8.1 RT app

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-8.1, hardware

I am trying to develop an application which will deal with the following hardware and perform the stuff mentioned. I want to know that would it be feasible .
1)

1. Wi-FI

   Scan for wi-fi , provide option to turn it off and on or reboot it .
   2)
2. Bluetooth

   Turn it off /on , make it discoverable if its not discoverable.
3. Apps

Get list of all apps that are installed and provide an option to kill them if they are running or uninstall them. The provision should also list the user the apps which he has sideloaded(need to know which all are the sideloaded apps).

4. Internet Connectivity

If internet is connected , check whether data is flowing or not.

5. Battery Status

Find all those apps which are consuming too much battery.Provide the option to uninstall them and lower the screen brightness and decrease the screen lock time

All these have to be implemented in an application that I want to develop.
I would be needing **links** for answers so that I can provide it in my feasibility report.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write a desktop app for this. Most of what you're looking for is completely out for a Windows 8.1 Runtime app. Windows 10 adds functionality for several of the bullet points, but in both versions you'll need a desktop app to manipulate other applications.

Universal Windows apps (aka Windows Runtime apps) run isolated and cannot generally affect the system or other apps. They can make changes only within their own context.

1 and 2: Windows 10 adds the [Windows.Devices.Radios.Radio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.devices.radios.aspx) class to address your radio bullets, but this functionality is not available in Windows 8.1 Runtime apps.

3: This cannot be done from a runtime app. A desktop app can enumerate a user's apps with the [Windows.Management.Deployment.PackageManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.aspx) class.

4: You can query connectivity with [Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.getinternetconnectionprofile.aspx)

5: This is not available in a Windows 8.1 Runtime app. In Windows 10 see [Windows.Devices.Power.Battery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.devices.power.battery.aspx)